# Matching the integral of a function on smaller open sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f: [0, 1] \to \mathbb R$ be Lebesgue integrable with $\int_0^1 f \, d \mu = C.$

**Question:** For every $K$ with $0 < K \leq 1$, does there exist an open subset $U$ of $[0, 1]$ of Lebesgue measure $K$ such that

$$\frac{1}{K} \int_U f \, d\mu = C?$$

*Remark:* This is relatively easily seen to be true if $U$ is not required to be open. However I am not sure about the open case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$\newcommand\op\oplus$Apparently, here $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure. Identify the interval $[0,1)$ with the (say) unit circle in a standard manner. Slightly more elementarily, for $x$ and $K$ in $(0,1)$, let
$$
(x,x\op K):=
\begin{cases}
(x,x+K)&\text{ if }x+K\le1,\\
(x,1)\cup(0,x+K-1)&\text{ if }x+K>1. 
\end{cases}
$$
Then
$$\int_0^1 dx\,\int_{(x,x\op K)} dt\,f(t)
=\int_0^1 dt\,f(t)\,\int_0^1 dx\,1(t\in(x,x\op K))
=\int_0^1 dt\,f(t)\,K.$$
Since $\int_{(x,x\op K)} dt\,f(t)$ is continuous in $x$, there exists some $x_*\in[0,1]$ such that
$$\int_{(x_*,x_*\op K)} dt\,f(t)=\int_0^1 dt\,f(t)\,K,$$
as desired.

---

Here are the graphs $\{(x,1(t\in(x,x\op 0.4)))\colon 0<x<1\}$ for $t=0.3$ (left) and $t=0.8$ (right):

[image]

Comment: Very slick proof!

Comment: @NateRiver : Thank you for your appreciation.